# How to set JNDI factory and provider URL in SpringBoot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jndi

I have a standalone Spring Boot based application that works as a JMS client. The provider is on another machine and exposes a JNDI context where all the JMS objects can be found.

In order for Spring Boot to be able to initialize the JNDI context, I have to specify Java system properties `java.naming.factory.initial` and `java.naming.provider.url` (by specifying them as `-Dproperty=value` when starting the program).

Further properties, e.g. the JNDI location of the JMS factory in the JNDI context, are specified via Spring Boot properties.

**My question is:** How can I specify the two properties for building the initial context via Spring properties as well (and not as system properties)? To my big surprise, I could not find an answer no matter where I searched.

Thank you.

Comment: Spring Boot does not use remote JNDI and therefor this use case is very uncommon

Comment: I mean, the library with the InitialContext class is located locally within my application, but I have to specify the class name as a java system property. Which is very uncommon in the spring world.

Comment: Sure but this is how JNDI works. You can also pass it when creating the InitialContext. Here is an old but still working example: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97688_16/generic.903/a97690/jndi.htm

Comment: Thank you for the link. I know how it works, and it works in my app. I'm just surprised that Spring has no means to set these parameters "in a Spring way". Spring could have some properties with well known names that would be used to fill the Hashtable that is used as the parameter when creating the InitialContext.

Comment: As I said using JNDI is not very common in the Spring environment. Therefor it was not requested by the developers

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/33680 has been declined.

Answer (score 0):

I agree, Spring JNDI is embarassingly underdocumented.
After hours of struggle, I have found this way of specifying a JNDI initial factory to perform a JNDI lookup, I am sure there are better ways but this can keep you going:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dbDataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/DatabaseName" expected-type="java.lang.String">
    <jee:environment>java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory</jee:environment>
</jee:jndi-lookup>
```